# Sharing into android app - limit to "text/plain"

Tags: android, text, android-sharing

I'm configuring my app to receive data form other apps, as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html.

I'm using the following intent filter to receive plain text:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, my app gets listed in the share menu for text files (in addition to plain text), and is called with `text/*` even though I specifically listed `text/plain`. Any idea how to limit incoming data to `text/plain` and avoid being listed in the share menu when the user shares text files?

Comment: when you say you only want to receive plain text, you mean like a text in your email and share it? can you explain how you are trying to select the texts?

Comment: @user1506104 - plain text can be any text the user selects. That works well for me. The problem I'm experiencing is that my app is also listed when the user shares a text file.

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, text file and selected text will trigger the same behavior. My suggestion may not be a direct solution to your problem. But is the closest thing I could think of to make your app work with selected text and/or text file. So with this, **your app will still be listed in share menu for text files**.

In your app, check if the shared data was text file or a selected text by simply checking the value of

`getIntent().getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)`

This should give you a filename if the user shared a text file. `Null` instead if the user shared a selected text.

Comment: I already have a simple way to distinguish between plain text and a text file based on the type of the received intent (`text/plain` vs `text/*`). As the question states, what I'm trying to do is to avoid being listed when text files are shared.